# unix/linux chmod to let everyone read every directory and file

Tags: linux, macos, mac, bash

I'm having file permission trouble backing up my MacbookPro through my LAN to my Windows computer.

I want to set permissions of all files and directories on MacbookPro to allow reading by all. On the Mac, I've been using two accounts over the years, so some files have this permission, some have that.

So I need to do: chmod -R a+r *

Also, I believe I also need to do a+x for all directories: chmod -R a+X *

Which means I can do both with: chmod -R a+r, a+X *

Is this correct? I'm asking so that I don't mess up access to my HD.

Comment: Maybe a better solution would be to find a way to make the backup run as root, or to back up at a block, rather then file level ?

Comment: Seconding davidgo's advice, changing the perms of your files that way could be a path to disaster. Use sudo to run your backup program as root and that should allow access to everything (although you may want to be circumspect about which file you back up, some things are best left local...)

Answer (score 4):

1. If you run the chmod command system-wide (on `/` directory), you'll definetly break your system. Some files in UNIX/Linux aren't meant to be read-able by everyone.
2. If you do this inside user's directory `/Users/<username>` you won't break your system, BUT you might expose some sensitive files to anyone in the system (eg. private keys for SSH). It's up to you what is the desired effect.
3. You can combine the chmods into `chmod -R a+rX <path>`.

Comment: or using the number syntax  sudo chmod -R 744 ~/Users/username/  but I agree with the others run it as root,   as a secondary learning experience check out [ https://github.com/rsnapshot/rsnapshot ] it is a opensource clone of TimeMachine it surely uses sane perms use that to learn your way around safely.

Comment: Nothing is in /home but /Users contains Guest/ Shared/ and my two accounts.  So, plan then is to use 'chmod -R a+rX' on my /User/... and also some directories that I have hanging off the root, but I will not change the root or any OS directories hanging off it.

Comment: Does a+rX make all files executable, or just directories?

Comment: @linuxdev2013 `chmod -R 744` is *not* a good idea, since that mode grants execute access to the user on all items (whether or not they're executable), but removes it for group and others. Execute access is required on directories to access items in the directory, so 744 will allow other users to see filenames (4 = read access) inside, but not actually do anything with the files and subdirectories. Use `a+rX` instead, since `X` automatically grants execute access *where it makes sense*, including all directories.

Comment: From a security stance  that is safer to see but not touch/act on but i reserve my  secure all the things mentality to myself :)